# Easy way to host/upload to my own rosjava maven repo

Tags: ros, gradle, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

## Problem

I've created two repos
https://github.com/WPIRoboticsProjects/gripjava_messages
and
https://github.com/WPIRoboticsProjects/grip_msgs

I would like to publish java artifacts that are created by the `gripjava_messages` project so that I can use them as a gradle dependency in my core (non ros built) application [GRIP](https://github.com/WPIRoboticsProjects/GRIP)

Am I better off opening a PR to try to add the `grip_msgs` project to this repository or should I try to host them on my own.

Both routes I'd be really grateful for some guidance. I'm running against brick walls in my search across the internet on how to do this correctly.

## Other details

I'm using a customized docker container to pull those two repos together into ROS on my system. (That all works on my end). I can get the messages to generate as expected. The files end up in the `$ROS_MAVEN_DEPLOYMENT_REPOSITORY` as I expect them to.

I was planning on doing the same thing with travis when I built the project.

I've also opened this as an issue here: https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_mvn_repo/issues/14

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229169/easy-way-to-host/upload-to-my-own-rosjava-maven-repo/) by [Jlleitschuh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26289/jlleitschuh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To answer my own question, the solution was here:

http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava/Tutorials/indigo/Uploading%20to%20Maven%20on%20Github

I ended up forking the rosjava/rosjava_mvn_repo. Ended up putting it here: https://github.com/WPIRoboticsProjects/rosjava_mvn_repo

Now I can use the dependencies I've created in my project.
Once I get a full release published I'll make a pull request to merge it in with the master repo.

---

Originally posted by [Jlleitschuh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26289/jlleitschuh/) with karma: 16 on 2016-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0